# python inherit classes specific exercise

Tags: python, inheritance

I have an `Pet` class and I need to define two classes `Cat` and `Dog`, the `Cat` class is inheriting from `Pet` and the `Dog` class needs to work with `eat_cat()` that will print `dog_name has eaten cat_name`. This is the given code:

```
class Pet:
   def __init__(self, name, eats):
      self.name = name
      self.eats = eats

# here i need to write my code.                 

cat = Cat(input("Cat name: "), input("Cat food: "))

dog = Dog(input("Dog name: "), input("Dog food: "))
dog.eat_cat(cat)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make an attempt at solving the problem yourself before asking for help. See [posting a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The mandatory: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

First, welcome to SO! You'll need to try yourself before asking as we are not here to do your job.

However I'm in a really good mood so I will only help you understand how your Pet class is built so you can try yourself, I will give you basic info to not overwhelm you with a complete list of terms because I feel like you're new to programming.

So, let's begin:

```
class Pet:
"""
Pretty straight forward, you create a new class named "Pet", it inherits nothing
(10secs of web searching will tell you how to inherit in python).
"""
   def __init__(self, name, eats):
   """
   This method is called a magic method and is called whenever you create an object
   A.K.A when you do x = Pet("Cortex", "Cheese")
   """

      # Here you define the properties of your object, your pet will have
      # a name and what it eats.
      self.name = name
      self.eats = eats
```

For the sake of lisibility I haven't put much infos inside the code block.

**The __init__ magic method**

When you call (create) a class object (a Pet here) this method will be called and executed automatically.

**The self keyword**

`self` is going to be the first argument for EVERY class method you implement and it represent the current instance of the class.

**The dot between self and whatever**

Well, this is how you access things in a Python object.

If you have IPython installed on your machine I suggest you open it because it can help you understand what is inside your objects.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = "foo"
        self.variable2 = "bar"
        self._variable3 = "baz"

    def get_variable3(self):
        return self._variable3
```

If you don't have IPython here's a screenshot:
[image: ipython screenshot if needed]

After pressing tab after the dot you can see what is inside your object. You can see, `variable1`, `variable2` and the method `get_variable3`.

```
a = MyClass()
a.variable1 # will return "foo"
a.variable2 # will return "bar"
a.get_variable3() # will return "baz"
```

If you are wondering why you don't see `_variable3` it's because I added the `_` in front of it's name and it's hiding it and that's why I created a method to see it.

## **Inheritance**

I know I said I wont help you with inheritance but here I still am.

Ultra short explanation:

Inheritance is taking everything from a Parent class and putting it inside a child class.

If I take the class I created earlier:

```
class MyChildClass(MyClass):
"""
This is how you specify inheritance, just put the parent class in the brackets
"""
    pass # the keyword for "do literally nothing"
```

Then if you create an instance of this class and look at what's inside:

[image: ipython screenshot]

Yep, this is the same, everything that was in the parent class (MyClass) was put inside the child one.

However as is, this is useless. The thing is you can define methods in the child class that will be specific to it:

[image: ipython screenshot mclass override]

Here I defined two methods in the child class. You can see that I redefined `get_variable3` to return `variable1` (for whatever reason), this means an MyChildClass object will return "foo" (the value in `variable1`) when calling this method whereas a MyClass object will return "baz".

I also created a brand new method which exists only in the MyChildClass and not in MyClass.

---

In your code you mention `dog.eat_cat(cat)`, from now you'll understand that this is a method inside the `dog` object that takes an argument.

I'm not the best at explaining things so I hope this could help you to at least grasp the basics.